# How to calculate average time differences by group?

Tags: r, date, grouping

My data looks like this:

```
data <- read.table(header=T, text= '
 PID     Date           Date.diff
  1      2020-01-01     0 
  1      2020-01-02     1
  1      2020-01-10     8
  2      2020-01-15     0
  3      2020-01-02     0
  4      2020-02-02     0
  4      2020-03-01     28
  4      2020-04-15     45
  ..     ..
 ')
```

Each date refers to a date that (in this case) a patient had a test done.

Using this code:

```
data$Date.diff <- unlist(tapply(data$Date, INDEX=data$PID, FUN=function(x)
  c(0, diff(as.numeric(x)))))
```

I was able to calculate the difference in dates (in days) as in the Date diff column.

If I calculate a mean based on Date diff, the result would be the mean number of days between all tests.

Now I would like to know the mean number of days between the 1st and 2nd, 2nd and 3rd ect.. tests, because I want to know if the intervals are getting shorter/longer.

Is that at all possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a test number column for each patient and then for each test number calculate the average of `Date.diff`.

```
library(dplyr)

data %>%
  group_by(PID) %>%
  mutate(test_number = row_number()) %>%
  group_by(test_number) %>%
  summarise(Date.diff = mean(Date.diff)) -> result
result
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That seems like a very good solution. However i'm getting an error: Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, Date.diff, value = list(test_number = 1:47,  : 
  replacement has 47 rows, data has 486.  Any ideas on how to solve this error?

Comment: I am not sure why you would get this error. It doesn't happen for me for the data that you have shared. Try restarting R and load only `dplyr` and run the answer. There are functions like `summarise`/`mutate` which might be masked from `plyr`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use lag to make an offset column in your data frame and find the interval duaration, here is a solution with dplyr and lubridate:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

data %>%
  mutate(across("Date", ymd)) %>%
  group_by(PID) %>%
  mutate(lag = lag(Date),
         diff2 = as.numeric(as.duration(interval(lag, Date)), "days")) %>%
  group_by(row_number()) %>%
  summarise(mean_days = mean(diff2, na.rm = TRUE), .groups = "drop")

# A tibble: 3 x 2
  `row_number()` mean_days
          <int>     <dbl>
1             1     NaN  
2             2      14.5
3             3      26.5
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `ave` is nicer to apply functions group-wise in order to create new columns, i.e. date differencing in your case. It already gives vectors back and avoids `unlist`ing.

```
dat$Date.diff <- with(dat, ave(as.numeric(Date), PID, FUN=function(x) c(0, diff(x))))

head(dat)
# PID       Date Date.diff
# 1   1 2020-01-03         0
# 2   1 2020-01-03         0
# 3   1 2020-01-18        15
# 4   1 2020-01-24         6
# 5   1 2020-01-24         0
# 6   2 2020-01-05         0
```

`tapply` is now rather useful to tabulate by group. We may use it here to calculate the `diff`erences of the `mean.Date`s very easily. (The `` `1`=0 `` is just cosmetcis).

```
c(`1`=0, diff(with(dat, tapply(Date, PID, FUN=mean.Date))))
#   1    2    3    4    5 
# 0.0  9.0 16.2  4.4 21.6
```

---

*Data*

```
dat <- structure(list(PID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), 
    Date = structure(c(18264, 18264, 18279, 18285, 18285, 18266, 
    18281, 18286, 18291, 18298, 18287, 18295, 18303, 18308, 18310, 
    18288, 18297, 18304, 18310, 18326, 18302, 18319, 18332, 18335, 
    18345), class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA, -25L), class = "data.frame")
```